# load a csv file into google sheet using python

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This would seem like a simple task but it's been eluding me for weeks.
It's pretty simple. I have a CSV file on my local drive. I want to append the rows into an existing Google Sheet (already has rows which I need to keep)
Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os.path
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import gspread as gs
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
# Set variables
imp_dir = "C:\\Users\\SRevelle\\Google Drive"
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('C:\\Users\\SRevelle\\Google Drive\\client_secret.json', scope)
client = gs.authorize(credentials)
service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

#Go get the file to load
os.chdir(imp_dir)
csvData = 'data.csv'

#Load it into dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(csvData)

# The ID of the spreadsheet to update.
spreadsheet_id = '1_XXXXXXXXXXXdwEOkETjEI0HrdP5M5Jh4XXXXXXXXXX'

# Values will be appended after the last row of the table.
rangeval = 'Test!A1:H1'  

# How the input data should be interpreted.
value_input_option = 'USER_ENTERED'

# How the input data should be inserted.
insert_data_option = 'INSERT_ROWS' 

request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=rangeval, valueInputOption=value_input_option, insertDataOption=insert_data_option, body={'data':df})
response = request.execute()
```

Here's the dataframe results from the csv file:

```
    Type    Number  Date     Number Description1    Description2    CAD$    USD$
0   Visa    1211    2/9/2021    0   MISC PAYMENT    RBC CREDIT CARD -20.88  0
1   MC      123     2/9/2021    0   testtest        xyz card        101.11  0
```

I've tried many different things and gone through many different errors. Sometimes I use .to_json just to see what error that will give me.

The error that I get with this code is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-2 in <module>
     34 
     35 insert_data_option = 'INSERT_ROWS'
---> 36 request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=rangeval, valueInputOption=value_input_option, insertDataOption=insert_data_option, body={'data':df})
     37 response = request.execute()

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py in method(self, **kwargs)
   1092 
   1093         headers = {}
-> 1094         headers, params, query, body = model.request(
   1095             headers, actual_path_params, actual_query_params, body_value
   1096         )

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\model.py in request(self, headers, path_params, query_params, body_value)
    158         if body_value is not None:
    159             headers["content-type"] = self.content_type
--> 160             body_value = self.serialize(body_value)
    161         self._log_request(headers, path_params, query, body_value)
    162         return (headers, path_params, query, body_value)

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\model.py in serialize(self, body_value)
    271         ):
    272             body_value = {"data": body_value}
--> 273         return json.dumps(body_value)
    274 
    275     def deserialize(self, content):
```

I see lots of people trying to do this but the solution is to download a some custom app, iteratively loop through the file or import it through the GUI. There MUST be an easier way!! Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The `body` parameter needs to be `{"values": df}`, but I don't think the Google service can handle a dataframe directly.  You may have to convert that to a list of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, at Sheets API, the dataframe cannot be directly used. This has already been mentioned by [Tim Roberts's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70074271/load-a-csv-file-into-google-sheet-using-python#comment123872792_70074271).
- The property of `data` is not existing in the method of spreadsheets.values.append. When you want to append the values using spreadsheets.values.append, please use `values`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```py
request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=rangeval, valueInputOption=value_input_option, insertDataOption=insert_data_option, body={'data':df})
response = request.execute()
```

##### To:

```py
values = df.values.tolist()
request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=rangeval, valueInputOption=value_input_option, insertDataOption=insert_data_option, body={'values': values})
response = request.execute()
```

If you want to add the header, please modify it as follows.

```py
values = [df.columns.values.tolist()]
values.extend(df.values.tolist())
request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=rangeval, valueInputOption=value_input_option, insertDataOption=insert_data_option, body={'values': values})
response = request.execute()
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

Comment: OH MY GOD!!! You beautiful person!!!! Thank you so much!! I just couldn't figure out that body={'values': values} part. You're the best!

Comment: Accepted. Thanks again.